# Google's 2-step verification - how to use application-specific password multiple times?

Tags: google-talk, login, authentication

When I generate an application-specific password to be used on `google talk`, Google states:

> **No need to memorize this password.
>  You should need to enter it only
>   once. Spaces don't matter.**

But this is confusing! I need to memorize this app-specific password. If I don't, how can I possibly log-in into my gtalk the next time? How is this password needed only once?

Comment: The application is supposed to remember the one time password.

Comment: @Bibhas What if I am using a shared computer?

Comment: Then two-step is not of any use to you. Two-step is for personal computers and apps that only you would use.

Comment: @Bibhas That's not strictly true. ASPs (App Specific Passwords) are only meant to be used with older software that don't support 2SV. The problem isn't just that Meysam is trying to share a computer, but that they are trying to use older software without support for 2SV while also on a shared computer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to reuse the application-specific password as long as the application is remembering the password you give it. If you don't let the application remember your password, I think you will have to generate a new one every time you want to log in.

Comment: Yes. The application is supposed to remember the one time password. It cannot be reused in any circumstances. The user have to generate a new password every time.

Comment: That's the whole point on having the 2-step.. to be secure.. not doing the same mistakes :)

Answer (score -1):

When you start using Google's 2-step verification, you need to provide a valid mobile phone number in which Gmail automation IVR can contact you.

After a logging into your Gmail account you will be getting a Phone call from IVR or a text message which you need to provide once this steps are completed you will be able to access your profile.

Comment: The verification code sent via the phone call is different from application-specific password.

Comment: You will get different access code whenever you log-in.

Comment: This "answer" doesn't actually address the question. I recommend removing it.